# Partial substitution / removing characters within regex matches

Tags: python, regex, string, substitution

I'm trying to remove the characters `` \/<>~?`% `` if they appear within three `&lt;`'s and `&gt;`'s.

For the string:

`<html><body>Multiple &lt;&lt;&lt;parameter&gt;&gt;&gt; options %to &lt;&lt;&lt;test/verify&gt;&gt;&gt; in &lt;&lt;&lt;one% g?o&gt;&gt;&gt;</body></html>`

(reads like `Multiple <<<parameter>>> options %to <<<test/verify>>> in <<<one% g?o>>>`.)

The final string I want is:

`<html><body>Multiple &lt;&lt;&lt;parameter&gt;&gt;&gt; options %to &lt;&lt;&lt;testverify&gt;&gt;&gt; in &lt;&lt;&lt;one go&gt;&gt;&gt;</body></html>`

Note that the '%' in '%to' is not removed since it's not within three `&lt;`'s and `&gt;`'s.

I tried these regex's so far:

```
>>> s = '<html><body>Multiple &lt;&lt;&lt;parameter&gt;&gt;&gt; options %to &lt;&lt;&lt;test/verify&gt;&gt;&gt; in &lt;&lt;&lt;one% g?o&gt;&gt;&gt;</body></html>'
>>>
>>> # just getting everything between <<< and >>> is easy
... re.sub(r'((?:&lt;){3})(.*?)((?:&gt;){3})', r'\1\2\3', s)
'<html><body>Multiple &lt;&lt;&lt;parameter&gt;&gt;&gt; options %to &lt;&lt;&lt;test/verify&gt;&gt;&gt; in &lt;&lt;&lt;one%? go&gt;&gt;&gt;</body></html>'
>>> re.findall(r'((?:&lt;){3})(.*?)((?:&gt;){3})', s)
[('&lt;&lt;&lt;', 'parameter', '&gt;&gt;&gt;'),
 ('&lt;&lt;&lt;', 'test/verify', '&gt;&gt;&gt;'),
 ('&lt;&lt;&lt;', 'one%? go', '&gt;&gt;&gt;')]
```

But trying to get a sequence of non-`` \/<>~?`% `` characters [doesn't work](https://regex101.com/r/vM8bD5/1) since anything containing it just gets excluded:

```
>>> re.findall(r'((?:&lt;){3})([^\\/<>~?`%]*?)((?:&gt;){3})', s)
[('&lt;&lt;&lt;', 'parameter', '&gt;&gt;&gt;')]
>>> re.findall(r'((?:&lt;){3})((?:[^\\/<>~?`%]*?)*?)((?:&gt;){3})', s)
[('&lt;&lt;&lt;', 'parameter', '&gt;&gt;&gt;')]
>>> re.findall(r'((?:&lt;){3})((?:[^\\/<>~?`%])*?)((?:&gt;){3})', s)
[('&lt;&lt;&lt;', 'parameter', '&gt;&gt;&gt;')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I went with was using the original `<<<.*>>>` regex and the [`repl` as a function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) option for `re.sub`:

```
>>> def illrepl(matchobj):
...     return ''.join([matchobj.group(1),
...                     matchobj.group(2).translate(None, r'\/<>~?`%'),
...                     matchobj.group(3)])
...
>>> re.sub(r'((?:&lt;){3})(.*?)((?:&gt;){3})', illrepl, s)
'<html><body>Multiple &lt;&lt;&lt;parameter&gt;&gt;&gt; options %to &lt;&lt;&lt;testverify&gt;&gt;&gt; in &lt;&lt;&lt;one go&gt;&gt;&gt;</body></html>'
>>> # verify that this is the final string I wanted:
... re.sub(r'((?:&lt;){3})(.*?)((?:&gt;){3})', illrepl, s) == '<html><body>Multiple &lt;&lt;&lt;parameter&gt;&gt;&gt; options %to &lt;&lt;&lt;testverify&gt;&gt;&gt; in &lt;&lt;&lt;one go&gt;&gt;&gt;</body></html>'
True
```

And since I don't need to change the `&lt;`'s and `&gt;`'s and I know the match is only for things within them, I could either use a non-capturing group for those parts of the regex or simplify the `illrepl` function a bit by just using the full match object at `group(0)` to remove illegal/invalid characters:

```
>>> def illrepl(matchobj):
...     # return matchobj.group(0).translate(None, r'\/<>~?`%')  # may have unicode so can't use this
...     return re.sub(r'[\/<>~?`%]*', '', matchobj.group(0))
...
>>> re.sub(r'(?:&lt;){3}(.*?)(?:&gt;){3}', illrepl, s)
'<html><body>Multiple &lt;&lt;&lt;parameter&gt;&gt;&gt; options %to &lt;&lt;&lt;testverify&gt;&gt;&gt; in &lt;&lt;&lt;one go&gt;&gt;&gt;</body></html>'
```

Not certain if there is a way I could have done this only via the regex and not needing to use the `illrepl` function to generate the replacements and having to use `re.sub` again within that.

Comment: You do need a callback to do this. It's the right choice.